# Jquery date not sorting in correct format

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have dates formatted as `MM/DD/YYYY`, but they are not sorting in the correct format. It adds junk data.

```js
function loadGrid() 
{

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    altRows: true,
    altclass: 'myAltRowClass',
    colNames:['Expense # ', 'Description', 'Expense Date ', 'Amount ', 'Status '],
    colModel:[
        {name:'expno',index:'expno', width:80, align:"center",sorttype:"string"},
        {name:'desc',index:'desc', width:150, align:"center",sortable:false},
        {name:'expdate',index:'expdate', align:"center",width:80, sorttype:'date',formatter:'date', formatoptions: {newformat:'mm/dd/yyyy'}, datefmt: 'mm-dd-yyyy'},
        {name:'expamnt',index:'expamnt',align:"left", width:70,sortable:false},
        {name:'estatus',index:'estatus', width:90, align:"center",sortable:false},
    ],

    beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {   return false;},
    hidegrid: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: "700",
    multiselect: false,
    caption: "My Expenses",
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    rowNum: 10,
    page: 1,
    pager: '#pager',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname:'expno',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    loadComplete: function () {
        $( ".selector" ).button({});

        $("#grid").effect("highlight", {}, 1500);
    }
});

for(var i=0;i<=gridData.length;i++)
    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData',i + 1, gridData[i]);
jQuery("#grid").setGridParam({rowNum:10}).trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

After this function the grid is loaded with 10 records. I want to sort those records using the Date. However, I am unable to sort in the correct order that I tried in the `datefmt` options.

Comment: Can you please formulate your question a bit more clearly?  I want to edit the question, but not sure what to edit.

Comment: What is doing the sorting?

Comment: If you include test data `gridData` one can reproduce the problem which you describe. By the way you can add `data: gridData` option to the grid instead of filling the grid in loop with respect of `addRowData` and reloading it with `reloadGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

You should verify that you use correct input format. You don't specified any `srcformat` property in `formatoptions` for the `formatter:'date'` so jqGrid suppose that you use default ISO 8601 (ISO8601Short) format of data: `"Y-m-d"`. For example the today date should be represented as the string `"2013-07-24"`. On the other side it seems me very suspected that you specified `datefmt: 'mm-dd-yyyy'` instead of `datefmt: 'yyyy-mm-dd'`. By the way I recommend you to use `formatoptions.srcformat` instead of `datefmt`.

The summary:

- change format of input data in `gridData[i].expdate` to `"Y-m-d"` (like "2013-07-24")
- change definition of `expdate` column to

```js
{name: "expdate", align: "center", width: 80, sorttype: "date",
formatter: "date", formatoptions: {newformat: "mm/dd/yyyy"}}
```

- add `id` property with the rowid which you want to every item of `gridData` array. If some column of your data already contains some unique values then you can alternatively add `key: true` to the corresponding column definition and don't need have `id` property in the input data. For example if `expno` contains unique values you can add `key: true` to the definition of `expno` column.
- use parameter `data: gridData` instead of filling grid in the loop with respect of `addRowData`.
- add `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true` option to the grid definition.